# Syntactic help: constraining functions to generic class

Tags: swift, generics, types, protocols

I have a structure that I simplified like this:

```swift
protocol Protocol {
    associatedtype T
    var common: T { get }
}

class Superclass<T>: Protocol {
    let common: T
    init(common: T) { self.common = common }
}

class IntClass<T>: Superclass<T> {
    let int = 5
}

class StringClass<T>: Superclass<T> {
    let string = "String"
}

class Example<P: Protocol> {
    let object: P
    init(object: P) { self.object = object }
    func common() -> P.T { object.common }
    func int() -> Int where P == IntClass<Any> { object.int }
    func string() -> String where P == StringClass<Any> { object.string }
}
```

I would like to create objects of the generic class `Example` where some of them contain an object of the also generic `IntClass` while others have a generic `StringClass` object. Now I’d like to add accessors on `Example` for `IntClass` and `StringClass` specific properties (so I don’t have to access them directly). They would need to be constrained to the respective class. These would be `int()` and `string()` in my example.

My example doesn’t work like intended though:

```swift
let intExample = Example(object: IntClass(common: Double(1)))

//  (= expected)
intExample.common() // Double 1

//  (= expected)
intExample.string() // Instance method 'string()' requires the types 'IntClass<Float>' and 'StringClass<Any>' be equivalent

//  (= not expected)
intExample.int() // Instance method 'int()' requires the types 'IntClass<Float>' and 'IntClass<Any>' be equivalent
```

I also tried:

```swift
func int() -> Int where P == IntClass<P.T> { object.int }
```

With these compiler complaints:

```
- Generic class 'Example' requires that 'P' conform to 'Protocol'
- Same-type constraint 'P' == 'IntClass<P.T>' is recursive
- Value of type 'P' has no member 'int'
```

And I tried:

```swift
func string<T>() -> String where P == StringClass<T> { object.string }
```

which, when using like `intExample.string()` results in `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred` (next to `Instance method 'string()' requires the types 'IntClass<Double>' and 'StringClass<T>' be equivalent`).
I don’t want `string()` to appear on an `Example<IntClass>` object in code completion.

Is there a syntax to accomplish what I want (anything with `typealias`?) or would I have to navigate around that problem?

Comment: Umm... You put a thumbs-up near the error message `Instance method 'string()' requires the types 'IntClass<Float>' and 'StringClass<Any>' be equivalent` in your code, but you said you are expecting `Value of type 'Example<IntClass<Double>>' has no member 'string'`. Please make up your mind.

Comment: Sorry, my thumbs up was intended to signal my expectation of the result. I clarifed this above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the properties you are trying to access here doesn't depend on the type parameter `T` of `IntClass` or `StringClass`, you can write two non generic protocols `HasInt` and `HasString`:

```
protocol HasInt {
    var int: Int { get }
}

protocol HasString {
    var string: String { get }
}

extension IntClass: HasInt { }
extension StringClass: HasString { }
```

Then you can constrain to the protocols, and access `int` and `string` through the protocol instead:

```
func int() -> Int where P: HasInt { object.int }
func string() -> String where P: HasString { object.string }
```

Comment: Thank you. The protocol solution seems a bit verbose. I still might have to go with it, because `func string<T>() -> String where P == StringClass<T> { object.string }` gives me `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred` when trying to use it like so: `intExample.string()`. I would expect `Value of type 'Example<IntClass<Double>>' has no member 'string'`.

Comment: @CelesteB if you look more closely (Look in the errors panel in Xcode), it gives you _both_ errors. Why do you have such strict requirements on what error messages to be produced in the first place!?

Comment: For clarity. I don’t want `.string()` to be offered on an `Example<IntClass>` object. The user of this API should not be confused.

Comment: I also don’t want `string()` to appear on an `Example<IntClass>` object in code completion.

Comment: `string` will not appear in autocomplete if you use the protocol solution. But then you are depending on the implementation details of Xcode (about what to show in autocomplete). And wanting a specific error message is just asking too much. It is rarely worth the effort to get a specific error message just to not confuse users. That should be the job of language designers, not you.

Comment: Assuming this is a case of bad language design, you are right (to a degree). My basic assumption though is that there is a way the designers intended my case to be treated; I just don’t know it yet.

Comment: Also, I consider not confusing my fellow colleagues a fundamental requirement for writing good code. Confused programmers, write more confusing code which leads to a lot of bugs ;)